# Approximating Sum of $\pi$ function

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\pi(x)$ be the prime counting function i.e. number of prime numbers less than or equal to $x$.

I know that there are lower bounds and upper bounds to this function but I was wondering if there is any good lower bound or upper bound for partial sums $\sum^{n}_{i=1}\pi(x_i)$ where the $x_i$ are natural numbers.
If you know about any book or paper that discussed this matter please let me know.

Comment: Wait so the $x_i$ are some natural number sequence, not just $1,2,3,\cdots$?

Comment: @Gareth Ma yeah, they are some natural numbers, not just 1, 2,3,...

Comment: A good approximation of $\pi(x)$ is $\text{Li}(x)$, since $\sum_{i\geqslant 1}\pi(x_i)$ diverges, we have
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\pi(x_i)\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\sim}\sum_{i=1}^n \text{Li}(x_i) $$
More precisely, the strong prime numbers theorem states that $\pi(x)=\text{Li}(x)+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{x}{(\ln x)^2}\right)$ thus
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\pi(x_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\text{Li}(x_i)+\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{x_i}{(\ln x_i)^2}\right) $$ I don't know if this is really what you expected.

Comment: Is there any good lower bound for this?

Comment: If there is no assumption on $x_i$ it is gonna be difficult.

Comment: Why do you expect there to be any result that’s nontrivial that is applicable to any sequence? Doesn’t sound right to me